# Is there a zip-like method in .Net?

Tags: .net, python, list, iteration

In Python there is a really neat function called `zip` which can be used to iterate through two lists at the same time:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3]
list2 = ["a", "b", "c"]
for v1, v2 in zip(list1, list2):
    print v1 + " " + v2
```

The above code should produce the following:

```
1 a
2 b
3 c
```

I wonder if there is a method like it available in .Net? I'm thinking about writing it myself, but there is no point if it's already available.

Comment: Could someone explain how this is different from just a "for" loop like: for (var i ; ; ){ var x = arr1[i]; var y = arr2[i]; }  I'm assuming there is a complex difference that I'm not seeing here.

Comment: Allen, there isn't, at least not for arrays. However, zip will work with anything you can iterate over, not just e.g. arrays.

Comment: Allen: zip() is an expression.  Your alternative is a block of code.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Update: It is built-in in C# 4 as [System.Linq.Enumerable.Zip<TFirst, TSecond, TResult> Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd267698(v=vs.110).aspx)

Here is a C# 3 version:

```cs
IEnumerable<TResult> Zip<TResult,T1,T2>
    (IEnumerable<T1> a,
     IEnumerable<T2> b,
     Func<T1,T2,TResult> combine)
{
    using (var f = a.GetEnumerator())
    using (var s = b.GetEnumerator())
    {
        while (f.MoveNext() && s.MoveNext())
            yield return combine(f.Current, s.Current);
    }
}
```

Dropped the C# 2 version as it was showing its age.

Comment: Would be nice to define Pair<,> as well or take an additional parameter that serves as the result selector.

Comment: Wow, I'm amazed. While I was typing my answer you provide almost 100% similar solution :)

Comment: This is one of the ideal situations for using the "var" keyword (if you were on 3.5):

    foreach (var pair in Zip(ints, strings))

You lose the noise of the Pair<int, string> declaration which for me is unneeded.

Comment: Garry: I agree, but C# 2.0 is still in much wider use so I thought I would stick to that for this example.

Answer (score 8):

As far as I know there is not. I wrote one for myself (as well as a few other useful extensions and put them in a project called [NExtension](http://www.codeplex.com/nextension) on Codeplex.

Apparently the Parallel extensions for .NET have a Zip function.

Here's a simplified version from NExtension (but please check it out for more useful extension methods):

```cs
public static IEnumerable<TResult> Zip<T1, T2, TResult>(this IEnumerable<T1> source1, IEnumerable<T2> source2, Func<T1, T2, TResult> combine)
{
    using (IEnumerator<T1> data1 = source1.GetEnumerator())
    using (IEnumerator<T2> data2 = source2.GetEnumerator())
        while (data1.MoveNext() && data2.MoveNext())
        {
            yield return combine(data1.Current, data2.Current);
        }
}
```

Usage:

```cs
int[] list1 = new int[] {1, 2, 3};
string[] list2 = new string[] {"a", "b", "c"};

foreach (var result in list1.Zip(list2, (i, s) => i.ToString() + " " + s))
    Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Answer (score 6):

Nope, there is no such function in .NET. You have roll out your own. Note that C# doesn't support tuples, so python-like syntax sugar is missing too.

You can use something like this:

```cs
class Pair<T1, T2>
{
    public T1 First { get; set;}
    public T2 Second { get; set;}
}

static IEnumerable<Pair<T1, T2>> Zip<T1, T2>(IEnumerable<T1> first, IEnumerable<T2> second)
{
    if (first.Count() != second.Count())
        throw new ArgumentException("Blah blah");

    using (IEnumerator<T1> e1 = first.GetEnumerator())
    using (IEnumerator<T2> e2 = second.GetEnumerator())
    {
        while (e1.MoveNext() && e2.MoveNext())
        {
            yield return new Pair<T1, T2>() {First = e1.Current, Second = e2.Current};
        }
    }
}

...

var ints = new int[] {1, 2, 3};
var strings = new string[] {"A", "B", "C"};

foreach (var pair in Zip(ints, strings))
{
    Console.WriteLine(pair.First + ":" + pair.Second);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There's also one in F#:

```ml
let zipped = Seq.zip firstEnumeration secondEnumation
```